# I need help writing a JAVA program that will open a named file after getting 10-integer value inputs and compute the average value of the numbers

Tags: java, exception, integer

I need to write a program that

1. Asks the user to enter in 10 integer values. If a non-integer value is entered, your program should display an error message and re-prompt the user to enter that value.
2. Stores the user's input in an array of integers.
3. Opens a file named data.txt. If the file does not exist, your program should create it. If the file cannot be opened, an error message is displayed and the program terminates.
4. Writes the ten integer values entered by the user to the file. Write each integer value on a separate line.
5. Closes the file.
6. Opens the file. If the file cannot be opened, an error message is displayed and the program terminates.
7. Reads the data back in from the file and sums the values as the data is read in.  An error message is displayed if there is an error reading the data, and the program is terminated.
8. Computes and displays the average value of the numbers in the file. Show the average with two digits after the decimal point.

I think I have the code correct to gather the 10 integers, but I can't get the error for non-integers to appear. I also don't know how to then go into opening the file data.txt to compute the average

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("\nThis program gets ten numbers from the user, and");
    System.out.println("computes and displays the average.");

    while (counter < 10) {
        System.out.print("Enter integer " + (counter + 1) + ": ");
        int value = input.nextInt();

        if (value > 0) {
            counter++;
            values.add(value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: input must be an integer.");
            input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track here is a slightly extended version of your original attempt, that should work, note it looks like Step 2 says to use an array of integers so I used that rather than an array list in your original attempt:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    private static final int NUM_INTEGERS = 10;
    private static final Integer[] USER_INTEGERS = new Integer[NUM_INTEGERS];
    private static final String DATA_FILE = "data.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_INTEGERS; i++) {
                USER_INTEGERS[i] = getIntegerInput(String.format("Enter integer %d: ", i + 1), scanner);
            }
        }
        try {
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(DATA_FILE));
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_INTEGERS; i++) {
                bufferedWriter.write(String.format("%d%n", USER_INTEGERS[i]));
            }
            bufferedWriter.close();
            double total = 0;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DATA_FILE));
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_INTEGERS; i++) {
                total += Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());
            }
            double average = total / NUM_INTEGERS;
            System.out.printf("Average of the %d numbers in %s: %.2f", NUM_INTEGERS, DATA_FILE, average);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static int getIntegerInput(String prompt, Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        int validInteger = -1;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                validInteger = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid input, try again...");
                System.out.print(prompt);
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
        return validInteger;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter integer 1: 4
Enter integer 2: 3
Enter integer 3: d
Error: Invalid input, try again...
Enter integer 3: 3
Enter integer 4: 4
Enter integer 5: zxcv
Error: Invalid input, try again...
Enter integer 5: 34
Enter integer 6: 2
Enter integer 7: 4
Enter integer 8: 8
Enter integer 9: 21
Enter integer 10: 6
Average of the 10 numbers in data.txt: 8.90
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked out and helped me understand what I needed.